# Flutter: app tabbars not showing labels on iOS while same code is showing labels on android fine

Tags: ios, flutter, tabs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whXSm.jpg)I have a flutter app
it has 3 tabs each with a label (text)
On android it is showing labels fine
But on iOS the labels are not showing.
I have tried many things but not getting any improvements
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Where are the screenshots? Please provide Android's and IOS's screenshots then we can solve problem easily